# Boolean conversion for fscanf()

Tags: c, parsing

In answering [How to do file I/O with bool in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77467782/2410359), I made a helper function that used `fgetc()` calls to substitute the missing `fscanf()` `bool *` specifier.

Also included is a test harness.

Review goals:

- Primary: Review `fscanf_bool()` for how well it achieved the above goal as well as any other concerns.
- Secondary: Review the *test harness* for completeness: How thoroughly did it exercise `fscanf_bool()`?  Suggested additional  tests?

---

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Read a 'bool' as if scanf() had a 'bool *' specifier.
 *
 * Read stream until:
 * * consume and ignore leading white-space.
 * * a complete case-less match to: "0", "1", "f", "t", "false", "true",
 * * end-of-file, or input error.
 * Non-matching characters are pushed back.
 *
 * On success, assign *b as true or false (1 or 0).
 *
 * Return 1 on success.
 * EOF on input error or immediate end-of-file.
 * 0 otherwise.
 */
int fscanf_bool(FILE *inf, bool *b) {
  int buf[5];
  int first_ch;

  // Ignore leading whitespaces.
  do {
    first_ch = buf[0] = fgetc(inf);
  } while (isspace(first_ch));

  // Test if the first character is enough.
  if (first_ch == '0' || first_ch == '1') {
    *b = (first_ch == '1');
    return 1;
  }
  if (first_ch == EOF) {
    return EOF;
  }
  first_ch = tolower(first_ch);
  if (first_ch != 'f' && first_ch != 't') {
    ungetc(buf[0], inf);
    return 0;
  }

  // Attempt to match "false" or "true".
  bool value = (first_ch == 't');
  static const char *ft[2] = {"false", "true"};
  const char *match = ft[value];
  for (unsigned i = 1; match[i]; i++) {
    buf[i] = fgetc(inf);
    int next_ch = tolower(buf[i]);
    if ((next_ch == EOF) && !feof(inf)) { // Input error
      return EOF;
    }
    if (next_ch != match[i]) {
      do {
        // Attempt to unget all "next" characters.
        // The first attempt should work if not EOF.
        // Subsequent ones may work, may fail.
        ungetc(buf[i--], inf);
      } while (i > 0);
      break;
    }
  }
  *b = value;
  return 1;
}

/*
 * Test code
 */

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test_fscanf_bool(const char *mode, bool initial, bool final, int rv,
    char next_ch, const char *stream_data) {
  int error = 0;
  bool b = initial;

  char *filename = "tmp.txt";
  FILE *outf = fopen(filename, "w");
  assert(outf);
  fputs(stream_data, outf);
  fclose(outf);

  FILE *inf = fopen(filename, mode);
  assert(inf);
  int retval = fscanf_bool(inf, &b);
  if (b != final) {
    printf("<%s> b:%d != expected b:%d\n", stream_data, b, final);
    error++;
  }
  if (retval != rv) {
    printf("<%s> retval:%d != expected retval:%d\n", stream_data, retval, rv);
    error++;
  }
  int ch = fgetc(inf);
  if (ch != next_ch) {
    printf("<%s> ch:%d != expected ch:%d\n", stream_data, ch, next_ch);
    error++;
  }
  fclose(inf);
  return error;
}

typedef struct {
  const char *mode;
  bool initial;
  bool final;
  int rv;
  char next_ch;
  const char *stream_data;
} test_data;

int tests_fscanf_bool(void) {
  test_data td[] = { //
      {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', "0x"}, // Happy path
          {"r", false, true, 1, 'x', "1x"}, //
          {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', "fx"}, //
          {"r", false, true, 1, 'x', "tx"}, //
          {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', "Fx"}, //
          {"r", false, true, 1, 'x', "Tx"}, //
          {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', "Falsex"}, //
          {"r", false, true, 1, 'x', "Truex"}, //
          {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', " \t\n\r\v0x"}, //
          {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', " 0x"}, //
          {"r", false, false, 0, 'X', "X"}, // Wrong upper char
          {"r", true, true, 0, 'x', "x"}, // Wrong lower char
          {"r", false, false, EOF, EOF, " \t\n\r\v"}, // Spaces
          {"r", false, false, EOF, EOF, ""}, // Empty
          {"w", false, false, EOF, EOF, "0x"}, // Input error
          // Below rely on more than 1 ungetc()
          {"r", false, false, 1, 'a', "Falsx"}, // Happy path
          {"r", false, true, 1, 'R', "TRux"}, //
      };
  size_t n = sizeof td / sizeof td[0];
  int error = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int e = test_fscanf_bool(td[i].mode, td[i].initial, td[i].final, td[i].rv,
        td[i].next_ch, td[i].stream_data);
    error += e;
    if (e)
      break;  // Comment out to run all tests.
  }
  printf("Error count %d\n", error);
  return error;
}

int main(void) {
  return tests_fscanf_bool() ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output

```
Error count 0
```

Comment: Pedantic note: `&& !feof(inf)` used instead of `&& ferror(inf)` to distinguish case when error flag is already set prior to the function call and end-of-file now occurs is not the same as input error having just occurred.

Comment: Is it undefined behavior to call it like so: `fscanf_bool(NULL, NULL);`?

Comment: @Harith Yes. It is UB, just like `fscanf(NULL, "%d", valid_ptr)` and `fscanf(valid_ptr, "%d", NULL)` are.

Answer (score 8):

Ooh, unit tests!  You know how to make me happy!

Let's look at the tests first, as that's valuable documentation of the expected use cases.

A purist might argue that these are not unit tests because they depend on an external resource (a filesystem where we can write `tmp.txt`), but that's understandable in C, which has no easy way to create any other `FILE*`.

And there's a minor mistake:

```
287905.c: In function ‘test_fscanf_bool’:
287905.c:81:20: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   81 |   char *filename = "tmp.txt";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
```

We can do better, though, by using `tmpfile()` to create the file somewhere more appropriate:

```
  FILE *f = tmpfile();
  if (!f) {
      perror("tmpfile");
      abort();
  }
  if (fputs(stream_data, f) == EOF || fflush(f)) {
      perror("fputs");
      abort();
  }
  f = freopen(NULL, mode, f);
  if (!f) {
      perror("reopen");
      abort();
  }
```

---

We have a problem with the test data structure:

```
typedef struct {
  const char *mode;
  bool initial;
  bool final;
  int rv;
  char next_ch;
  const char *stream_data;
} test_data;
```

If we want to use `EOF` in `next_ch`, that member really needs to be an `int` so that we can distinguish from a valid `char` that compares equal to `EOF`.  We'll also need to change the corresponding argument of `test_fscanf_bool()`.

Actually, the arguments to `test_fscanf_bool()` exactly copy the `test_data` struct, so it may be better to simply pass a pointer to the entry in the test array.

---

None of the test cases demonstrate a true `initial` becoming false - we should ensure that we're not just skipping the assignment.

We also have no test for e.g. `tr` - demonstrate that we correctly back up from end-of-file during the lookahead.

---

> ```
> if (e)
>   break;  // Comment out to run all tests.
> ```

I recommend running all the tests always.  Exiting on the first failure is frustrating when debugging.  When this early exit is enabled, the "error count" message is misleading.

---

Let's move on to the implementation now.

I'd change the `if` chain to a `switch`:

```
  switch (first_ch) {
  case EOF:
      return EOF;
  case '0':
      *b = false;
      return 1;
  case '1':
      *b = true;
      return 1;
  case 'f': case 'F':
      *b = false;
      break;
  case 't': case 'T':
      *b = true;
      break;
  default:
      /* not a bool string */
      ungetc(first_ch, inf);
      return 0;
  }
```

Then can move the declaration of `buf` down to just before the loop where it's used.

I would declare the static variable `ft` const:

```
  static const char *const ft[2] = {"false", "true"};
```

I'm a bit uncomfortable ignoring the return value of `fungetc()` for the non-EOF values.  That said, it's hard to know what we should do when the target's push-back buffer is too small for our purposes; maybe ignoring it is correct.

We don't really need `next_ch` (or for that matter, `first_ch`).  I don't think it's any less clear to use the `buf[]` entries.

---

## Modified code

Some of my changes here are personal preferences, but pick and choose what you like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Read a 'bool' as if scanf() had a 'bool *' specifier.
 *
 * Read stream until:
 * * consume and ignore leading white-space.
 * * a complete case-less match to: "0", "1", "f", "t", "false", "true",
 * * end-of-file, or input error.
 * Non-matching characters are pushed back.
 *
 * On success, assign *b as true or false (1 or 0).
 *
 * Return 1 on success.
 * EOF on input error or immediate end-of-file.
 * 0 otherwise.
 */
int fscanf_bool(FILE *inf, bool *b)
{
    int buf[5];

    // Ignore leading whitespace.
    do {
        buf[0] = fgetc(inf);
    } while (isspace(buf[0]));

    // Test the first character.
    switch (buf[0]) {
    case EOF:
        return EOF;
    case '0':
        *b = false;
        return 1;
    case '1':
        *b = true;
        return 1;
    case 'f': case 'F':
        *b = false;
        break;
    case 't': case 'T':
        *b = true;
        break;
    default:
        /* not a bool string */
        ungetc(buf[0], inf);
        return 0;
    }

    // If we got here, we saw a 't' or 'f' (modulo case).
    // Advance past full word "false" or "true".
    static const char *const ft[2] = {"false", "true"};
    const char *match = ft[*b];
    for (unsigned i = 1;  match[i];  i++) {
        buf[i] = fgetc(inf);
        if ((buf[i] == EOF) && !feof(inf)) {
            // Input error
            return EOF;
        }
        if (tolower(buf[i]) != match[i]) {
            do {
                // Attempt to unget all "next" characters.
                // The first attempt should work, ignoring EOF.
                // Subsequent ones may work, but we ignore failures.
                ungetc(buf[i--], inf);
            } while (i > 0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

````
/*
 * Test code
 */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char mode[2];
    bool initial;
    bool final;
    int rv;
    int next_ch;
    char stream_data[10];
} test_data;

int test_fscanf_bool(const test_data *data)
{
    FILE *f = tmpfile();
    if (!f) {
        perror("tmpfile");
        abort();
    }
    if (fputs(data->stream_data, f) == EOF || fflush(f)) {
        perror("fputs");
        abort();
    }
    f = freopen(NULL, data->mode, f);
    if (!f) {
        perror("reopen");
        abort();
    }

    int error = 0;
    bool b = data->initial;
    int retval = fscanf_bool(f, &b);
    if (b != data->final) {
        printf("<%s> b:%d != expected b:%d\n",
               data->stream_data, b, data->final);
        ++error;
    }
    if (retval != data->rv) {
        printf("<%s> retval:%d != expected retval:%d\n",
               data->stream_data, retval, data->rv);
        ++error;
    }
    int ch = fgetc(f);
    if (ch != data->next_ch) {
        printf("<%s> ch:%d != expected ch:%d\n",
               data->stream_data, ch, data->next_ch);
        ++error;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return error;
}

int tests_fscanf_bool(void)
{
    static const test_data td[] = {
        {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', "0x"}, // Happy path
        {"r", false, true, 1, 'x', "1x"},
        {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', "fx"},
        {"r", true, false, 1, 'x', "fx"},  // yes, we overwrite
        {"r", false, true, 1, 'x', "tx"},
        {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', "Fx"},
        {"r", false, true, 1, 'x', "Tx"},
        {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', "Falsex"},
        {"r", false, true, 1, 'x', "Truex"},
        {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', " \t\n\r\v0x"},
        {"r", false, false, 1, 'x', " 0x"},
        {"r", false, false, 0, 'X', "X"}, // Wrong upper char
        {"r", true, true, 0, 'x', "x"}, // Wrong lower char
        {"r", false, true, 1, EOF, "T"}, // EOF during lookahead
        {"r", false, true, 1, 'R', "TR"}, // EOF during lookahead
        {"r", false, false, EOF, EOF, " \t\n\r\v"}, // Spaces
        {"r", false, false, EOF, EOF, ""}, // Empty
        {"w", false, false, EOF, EOF, "0x"}, // Input error (write-only stream)
        // Below rely on more than 1 ungetc()
        {"r", false, false, 1, 'a', "Falsx"}, // Happy path
        {"r", false, true, 1, 'R', "TRux"},
    };
    size_t n = sizeof td / sizeof td[0];
    int error = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < n;  ++i) {
        error += test_fscanf_bool(td + i);
        //if (error) { break; }  // Uncomment to quit on first failure.
    }
    printf("Error count %d\n", error);
    return error;
}

int main(void)
{
    return tests_fscanf_bool() ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```
````

Comment: Re; "warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]" --> `char *filename = "tmp.txt";` is a `char *` initializing a `char *`.  `const` would be a good idea, yet the warning looks like a C++ one.

Comment: Yes, member `char next_ch;` should be `int next_ch;`.

Comment: Yes, "None of the test cases demonstrate a true initial becoming false" is a good catch.

Comment: Yes, 2nd `const` good for `static const char *const ft[2]`.

Comment: The `switch (buf[0])` idea has a subtle improvement not readily seen: Using `tolower()` brings in locale dependent lowering that might match t, or f for some extended ASCII value. This concerned is not saved though in the `for (unsigned i = 1;  match[i];  i++)` loop. I think the pedantic way is to have `ft_lower[2] = {"false", "true"};` and `ft_upper[2] = {"FALSE", "TRUE"};` and test against both, dropping `tolower()` altogether. (I am confident `isspace()` is OK to match `fscanf()` functionality.)

Comment: "That said, it's hard to know what we should do when the target's push-back buffer is too small for our purposes; maybe ignoring it is correct." echoes a similar concern I have.  Further, if `fscanf()` was ever modified to handle `bool *`, it may have better tools than multi-`ungetc()`.

Comment: Same problem exist today with `fscanf(inf, "%f%c", &f, &ch)` and input like `"0xy"`.  Since that  `"0x"` could begin a `"0x123.45p67"`, yet does not, `y` gets pushed back and maybe `x`.  So what does `ch` get?

Comment: I no longer have access to HP-UX or AIX systems; the Linux environments I have support huge push-back buffers, so I can't test that situation for you.  :(

Comment: Re your first comment: in C++, that would be an _error_, not a warning.  C string literals have type `char*` for historical reasons, but it's UB to attempt to modify them, so the warning is a valuable one and I always enable it.

Comment: OK, so no real problem with the compiler warning, yet problem with this answer calling this part of compliant code here a _mistake_.  In this case, it is more like a weak coding practice to not have a `const *` object.

Comment: @chux, I wrote "mistake" because I assumed it was unintentional - out of character with the quality of the remainder.  Perhaps that assumption means that I made a mistake.  :-)

Comment: Toby, fair enough.  It is that there is the central code to review: `fscanf_bool()`.  The test harness about it only needs review of its major points.  I have failed to adequately focus the review on the first.  I'll try better next time.